# NPM: Only install missing - how to speed up npm install

Tags: tfs, msbuild, npm, azure-devops, npm-install

I have a lot of devdepencencies in my npm script. `npm install` takes a few minutes the first time, that's ok.

But since I'm integrating with TFS build server, it only needs to npm install once. After that, npm install is just wasting time because it takes 2-3 minutes to just determin the packages are already installed. Also, it seems to always reinstall the packages with -g global flag, even when existing.

How can I make it check if packages exist, and if so, skip npm install?

Comment: Are you using the hosted build agent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [npm-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache) as an alternative way if you use [on-premise build agents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows) for build.

> It is useful for build processes that run [npm|bower|composer|jspm]
>   install every time as part of their build process. Since dependencies
>   don't change often, this often means slower build times. npm-cache
>   helps alleviate this problem by caching previously installed
>   dependencies on the build machine. npm-cache can be a drop-in
>   replacement for any build script that runs [npm|bower|composer|jspm]
>   install.
>
> **How it Works**
>
> When you run npm-cache install [npm|bower|jspm|composer], it first
>   looks for package.json, bower.json, or composer.json in the current
>   working directory depending on which dependency manager is requested.
>   It then calculates the MD5 hash of the configuration file and looks
>   for a filed named .tar.gz in the cache directory ($HOME/.package_cache
>   by default). If the file does not exist, npm-cache uses the system's
>   installed dependency manager to install the dependencies. Once the
>   dependencies are installed, npm-cache tars the newly downloaded
>   dependencies and stores them in the cache directory. The next time
>   npm-cache runs and sees the same config file, it will find the tarball
>   in the cache directory and untar the dependencies in the current
>   working directory.

And you can also try with [npm-install-missing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-missing).

However, if you are using VSTS Hosted Build Agent, then you cannot do this since every time you queue a build with Hosted Build Agent, a clean build agent is assigned for the build. That means there is no dependency package installed on the agent. You need to perform a complete npm install.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Wish I could use the same build agent with my own user profile each time. No biggie because we're going to migrate to internal TFS which will work with npm-cache since the agent is the same each build.